# PHP Check URL parameters against an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using the following code to echo a part of a URL and my dynamic URL now looks like this.

```
https://example.test/test.php?name=living-room
```

But the condition is that, it will only echo if the `name` part of the URL is in my array.

```php
$array = array('kitchen', 'bedroom', 'living room', 'dining room');
if (in_array($_GET['name'], $array))
{echo $_GET['name'];}  
else {header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");}
```

What I'm trying to do is treat the `-` in URL's `name` part as spaces.

For example, `living-room` should be equal to `living room` in my array and it should echo the value in my array (`living room`) instead of (`living-room`).

1. So if the URL's value is `living-room`, we check the array and since `living room` exists in the array `living room` will get echoed.
2. In the same way as before, if the URL's value is `dining-room`, since `dining room` exists in my array, `dining room` will get echoed.

I'm having a hard time finding the correct logic to this.

Comment: It's fine if you're eager to learn PHP, but could you please, on Stackoverflow, before creating new contributions research your topic in existing contributions first? [Your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68445620) follows borderline a similar pattern. There is also the [PHP documentation](https://php.net/docs) available for studying which has the bricks you can build the logic on.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service. 

You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example. For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace "`-`" (U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS) with " " (U+0020 SPACE) in your string like so:

```php
header("Content-Type: text/plain");

$array = ['kitchen', 'bedroom', 'living room', 'dining room'];
$needle = str_replace("-", " ", $_GET['name']);
if (in_array($needle, $array, true)) {
    echo $needle, "\n";
} else { 
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do a string replace while echoing the string from URL parameter. You can do something like this:

```php
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
$name = $_GET['name'];
$name = str_replace("-"," ",$name); // Replace - with space
    
$array = ['kitchen', 'bedroom', 'living room', 'dining room'];
    
if (in_array($name, $array, true)) {
    // Found
    echo $name, "\n"; 
} else {
    // Not found
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```